# GitVersion configuration struggel and how to append one more version after Patch

Tags: git, version-control, gitversion

Cant get my way around a nice git versioning using `develop` as a CI for nuget creation. Some time we also do nugets based on our feature branch in order to properly test integrations and dependencies from other systems.
When we do this we want the possibility to merge dependant system with feature branch nuget as that PR might be quite small and easy to review.

And here is our issue because if we do this we need to know at what stage develop nuget is compared to feature branch nuget so we get all our develop features + new feature branch code.

*One solution for this i can see is to add two additional increments*

1. Is there a way to add additional increments so it's easy to differenciate what stage develop is at compared to my feature branch proposed below (almost like google has in chrome version Version 83.0.4103.**116**)
2. how can i drop the number part from `develop` configuration -> 2.5.22-b**2886**

```
Major = breaking changes
Minor = release
Patch = hotfix
? = develop <- increment on each merge to develop target from others than master
```

Current configuration generates:

```
Base develop:
  develop
  2.5.21-b2881
Old feature branch:
  feature/git
  2.5.21-a-git0003 <- .21 indicates develop, but at the same time when branching from develop we always get +1 patch increment indicating this is out of date
Merge develop to feature:
  feature/git
  2.5.22-a-git0004 <- .22 now we know that develop is up to date as we are +1 ahead
Merge feature to develop (no updates was done after merge but feature was ahead):
  develop
  2.5.22-b2886 <- branch feature/git is now same as develop
Branch release:
  release/git
  2.5.23-rc0000 <-- would like this to remain at .22 because its a release from current develop
Merge release to master
  master
  2.6.0
Merge master to develop
  develop
  2.6.0-b2889
```

What i would like:

```
Base develop:
  develop
  2.5.0.21-b2881
Old feature branch:
  feature/git
  2.5.0.20-a-git0003 <- .20 indicates develop is out of date
Merge develop to feature:
  feature/git
  2.5.0.21-a-git0004 <- .21 now we know that develop is up to date
Merge feature to develop (no updates was done after merge but feature was ahead):
  develop
  2.5.0.22-b2886 <- increment as develop has updated
Branch release:
  release/git
  2.5.0.23-rc0000 <-- would like this to remain at .22 because its a release from current develop
Merge release to master
  master
  2.6.0
Merge master to develop
  develop
  2.6.0.0-b2889 <- i know what the number 2889 is, but i dont want this number increment
```

gitversion /showconfig

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: Mainline
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
next-version: 2.0.0
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: /?releases?[/-]
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
tag-pre-release-weight: 60000
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches:
  master:
    mode: Mainline
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master$
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 55000
  develop:
    mode: Mainline
    tag: b
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    source-branches: []
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 0
  release:
    mode: Mainline
    tag: rc
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - master
    - support
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  feature:
    mode: Mainline
    tag: a-{BranchName}
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^(features?|task|bug|refactor)[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - master
    - release
    - feature
    - support
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  hotfix:
    mode: Mainline
    tag: hf
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - master
    - support
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  pull-request:
    mode: Mainline
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - master
    - release
    - feature
    - support
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  support:
    mode: Mainline
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^support[/-]
    source-branches:
    - master
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 55000
ignore:
  sha: []
commit-date-format: yyyy-MM-dd
merge-message-formats: {}
update-build-number: true
```

GitVersion.yaml

```
next-version: 2.0.0
mode: Mainline
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
minor-version-bump-message: '/?releases?[/-]'
ignore:
  sha: []
branches:
  master:
    increment: Patch
    is-mainline: false
  develop:
    tag: b
    increment: Patch
    is-mainline: true
  release:
    increment: Patch
    tag: rc
  feature:
    increment: Patch
    tag: a-{BranchName}
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    regex: ^(features?|task|bug|refactor)[/-]
  hotfix:
    increment: Patch
    tag: hf
  pull-request:
    increment: Patch
  support:
    increment: Patch
    is-mainline: false
```

Comment: Have you tried `mode: ContinuousDeployment` on `develop`? Also, you don't seem to be using the `FullSemVer` for your version numbers; it will contain an ever incrementing `buildmetadata` that is the number of commits since the last tag.

If you want your `release/*` branches to have a specific version number, you will have to name the branch with the exact version number you want. You can't expect GitVersion to create a stable version number for some branches and commits and not for others, given the same configuration.

Comment: @AsbjørnUlsberg Unforunetly using `mode: ContinuousDeployment` on develop but Mainline as default it results in this:
Feature branch: 2.6.0-a-7734-calculate0043
Develop: 2.1.0-b2878

Making them out of sync from eachothers :(

Comment: I just merged the PR [Add support for next-version in mainline mode](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/pull/2356) which may be relevant to you as you seem to be using `next-version` in combination with `mode: Mainline`. I'm not sure when we'll have a new stable published with that in, but you can grab an [artifact from the build](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/actions/runs/168564832) and try it out.